# Python spacing and %

Tags: python, spacing

I need to output this:

Video Games: 8/8 (or 100.0%)

This is the code for the mark out of 8:

```
total = points+pointsTwo+pointsThree+pointsFour
```

How would I write this code to output exactly what I wrote above with the exact spacings?

I tried:

```
print("Video Games:", total, "/8  (or", total*100/8,"%)")
```

But there is a space; 8 /8 instead of 8/8 and another space; 100.0 % instead of 100.0%

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [String formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) (for both Python 2 or 3) like this:

```
out = "Video Games: {total}/8 (or {percent}%)".format(total=total, percent=total*100/8)
print(out)
```

In Python 3.0 the above gives:

```
Video Games: 7/8 (or 87.5%)
```

or in Python 2.0 you get the below (due to integer division):

```
Video Games: 7/8 (or 87%)
```

edit: **All credit to Gnibbler for this:**

It can be done in shorter, more controlled way by letting the string formatter take care of calculating the percentage:

```
out = "Video Games: {total}/8 (or {ratio:.2%})".format(total=total, ratio=total/8.0)
print(out)
```

Also giving (note the decimal points and trailing zero):

```
Video Games: 7/8 (or 87.50%)
```

Comment: Check out the percentage example in the link you posted

Comment: @gnibbler !! That is astounding! I have never not learned anything from your answers or comments!!!

Answer (score 1):

`str.format` has a special trick for printing percentages.

```
"Video Games: {total}/8 or {percent:.1%}".format(total=total, percent=total/8.0)
```

the `.1` means "one decimal place", the `%` means it's a percentage, so it's implicitly multiplied by 100

Comment: Depending on the version of python though the percent value may need to be divided by a float to get a non-zero value. In Python 2, `7/8 == 0`.

Comment: Looks like it may be Python3, but I should add a `.0` to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
print "Video Games: %d/8 (or %0.2f%%)" % (total, total*100/8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has too many different ways of making formatted strings.  My favorite <s>has not yet been mentioned</s> has only been briefly mentioned:

```
print "Video Games: %d/8 (or %.1f%%)" % (total, total*100/8.0)
```

For Python 2.7 and below, be careful about integer division (that's why I have `8.0` in the denominator).  The percent is `%%` to ensure that it is interpreted as a literal `%`.

There's an extended version of this for making big strings with lots of replacements, in which you might lose track of which replacement corresponds to which in the string.  It goes like this:

```
percentage = total*100/8.0
print "Video Games: %(total)d/8 (or %(percentage).1f%%)" % vars()
```

The `vars()` call produces `{'total': 8, 'percentage': 100.0, ...}`, including all variables in your current namespace, so that it will know what to insert for `%(total)d` and `%(percentage).1f`.  It's more verbose, but more self-documenting.  If you didn't want to create a new variable for `percentage`, you could have done:

```
print "Video Games: %(total)d/8 (or %(percentage).1f%%)" % {"total": total, "percentage": total*100/8.0}
```

I started using this when I learned that string concatenation with `+` iteratively copies strings: building a large string with many `+` signs can be very inefficient, approaching O(n^2) in string length.  For most purposes, it's a microscopic speed optimization, but I just got into the habit of it and liked how much easier it is to read the code.

Comment: -1 %-formatting is considered [deprecated and may disappear at some point in the future](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations)